# PrintWriter#println method not working as expected

Tags: java, printwriter

This code:

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, false));
output.println("something\n");
output.println("something else\n");
```

Outputs:

```
something
something else
```

Instead of:

```
something

something else
```

I tried using "\r\n" instead of just "\n" but it just doesn't work like how I want it to. How do I fix this?

P.S. I'm using windows 7

Comment: use -- output.print("something\n\n");

Comment: can you post an hexdump of the output file ?

Comment: What does output.println("something"); - without any \n - print?

Comment: Are you checking the content of the file with Notepad? It does not display the single `\n` as a line break but it exists as you can verify when you display it with a different texteditor or even hexeditor.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014287/is-there-a-way-to-make-printwriter-output-to-unix-format) and also check output using an advanced text editor so you can see what characters are actually being output.

Comment: @JamesPoulson make your comment an answer and you'll get my +1.

Comment: @halex and James, Thanks for the tip! I installed notepad++ and things are showing up fine just as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works like a charm, just check the file with a proper programmers editor. 
(or as I suggested before, take a look at an hex dump of the file)

Answer (score 6):

You can concatenate system's newline to separate your lines:

```
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    output.println("something" + newLine);
    output.println("something else" + newLine);
```

Comment: This is also only guaranteed to work if the file is viewed in the same system as the program was run. But it's cleaner than using `\n` or `\r\n` or so. +1

Answer (score 2):

This

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter output;
        try {
            output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("asdf.txt", false));
            output.println("something\n");
            output.println("something else\n");
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Works well for me, I get an *asdf.txt* like this

> something
>
> something else

I am using jre1.7, what are you using?

Comment: The problem was not java. As advised above, I downloaded an advanced editor (notepad++) and things showed up just fine. Thanks for responding to my post!

Comment: Oõ What editor where you using that was not able to show `\n` properly?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine. You must be using notepad for the output. Try using a different text editor like notepad++. You'll get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.works;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/*
 * @author: sarath_sivan
 */
public class PrintWriterExample {

    private static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String outputFile = "C:/Users/sarath_sivan/Desktop/out.txt";
        PrintWriter output = null;
        try {
            output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, false));
            output.println("something" + NEW_LINE);
            output.println("something else" + NEW_LINE);
            output.flush();
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Output]